# How to sorting data by input?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have problem with sqlite3 in Python. I want sorting data from database by inputing date.

Here is my code, is it good way?

```
 if choice == 1:
        # Suma 'Wartość' z simple.db 
       
        dt = input()
        dt2 = input()
        cursor.execute('''
            SELECT 
                SUM(Wartość),
                Data 
            FROM 
                kalendarz
            WHERE
                Data between () and () VALUES (?, ?);''', (dt, dt2))
```

Comment: Do you want to sort dates or to select dates within an interval ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are summing the column `Wartość` without group by try this instead:

```
 if choice == 1:       
    dt = input()
    dt2 = input()
    cursor.execute(f'''
        SELECT 
            Wartość,
            Data 
        FROM 
            kalendarz
        WHERE
            Data between '{dt}' and '{dt2}'
        ORDER BY
            Data''')
```

Comment: Nah :(  It's didn't work with me

```Exception has occurred: OperationalError
near "ORDERBY": syntax error
  File "C:\Users\Coding\Desktop\Coding\Ksiegowa\KPiR.py", line 27, in <module>
    cursor.execute(f''' ```